# Open Jupyter Notebook via Python code subprocess

Tags: selenium, google-maps, widget, jupyter

I explain the idea and then the problem I got. The idea is open Jupyter Notebook via Python code, retrieve the token, and with another Python script go Selenium to the jupyter Notebook and get screenshot of the Google Maps Widgets I have there.

So I open Jupyter Notebook:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('jupyter notebook', shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Console:

```
[I 18:03:46.460 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:03:46.460 NotebookApp] The port 8889 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:03:46.460 NotebookApp] The port 8890 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:03:46.538 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 18:03:46.538 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 18:03:46.611 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\maranda\Desktop\PycharmProjects
[I 18:03:46.611 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 18:03:46.611 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8891/?token=6ff95c98d52d38b3a607f605776a83271f7d15c176a610ac
[I 18:03:46.611 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 18:03:46.711 NotebookApp] 

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/maranda/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-26572-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8891/?token=6ff95c98d52d38b3a607f605776a83271f7d15c176a610ac
[W 18:03:46.720 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/76abff7e-7bd6-459e-9ace-9de7684d9b40/channels?session_id=872d7412fb4b464b8ee5d50bc63d94f4 (127.0.0.1): Kernel does not exist: 76abff7e-7bd6-459e-9ace-9de7684d9b40
[W 18:03:46.741 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/76abff7e-7bd6-459e-9ace-9de7684d9b40/channels?session_id=872d7412fb4b464b8ee5d50bc63d94f4 (127.0.0.1) 29.42ms referer=None
[W 18:03:54.745 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 76abff7e-7bd6-459e-9ace-9de7684d9b40:872d7412fb4b464b8ee5d50bc63d94f4
```

It works but I want to save the output line of the NotebookApp where is appears the token in order to save it (write in *.txt for example) and then with another Python script, use Selenium to connect to my Jupyter Notebook and then get Selenium Screenshot of the Google Maps Widgets I got in my Jupyter Notebooks.

When I try to open the Jupyter Notebook via Selenium, it requests the token from me so I need to read it from the output of the subprocess above.

The final aim is getting screenshots of the Google Maps Widgets as I want to get the traffic layer at a specific moment, if I export the widget via

```
embed_minimal_html('export.html', views=[fig])
```

I got the problem that I need to execute the exported HTML and it gets the traffic of the moment when it is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could do it in a different way.

First I create the GMaps widgets and export them to local folder:

```
import gmaps
from ipywidgets.embed import embed_minimal_html
import ipywidgets
print(ipywidgets.__version__)
API_key = 'XXX'
gmaps.configure(api_key = API_key)
layer = gmaps.Traffic()
punto = (Lat, Long) 
fig = gmaps.figure(center=punto, zoom_level=13, layout = {'width' : '100%', 'height' : '500px'})
fig.add_layer(layer)
embed_minimal_html('Exported.html', views=[fig])
fig
```

IMPORTANT: I use ipywidgets.**version** = 7.2.1 as the oldest version 7.4.2 throws errors with this code.

After obtaining the 'Exported.html' we need to open it via Browser Chrome, I use Selenium, then I click the download button the GMaps widget has via Selenium also:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--test-type")
options.add_argument("window-size=700,700")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe path')
url = 'C:\Exported.html'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()
driver.close()
```

And that's all. I hope someone can be helped with this code,

Manuel.